# Make Win10 auto-detect audio instead of requiring opening the 'Sounds' panel

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, hardware-detection

I use a television as my main monitor on Windows 10 Pro and connect to it via HDMI. This works fine for the most part, however if I turn the TV off for more than a couple minutes, when I turn it back on, Windows doesn't detect its speakers.

- I have a workaround: Sound Control Panel > Sounds tab (see screenshot), as just opening it, without doing anything, makes Windows detect the speakers.
- Volume Up/Down/Mute buttons, Volume Mixer panel, and Settings > Sound panel do nothing 
   
  [image: IMG:]

Since it's such a trivial thing that makes Windows detect the speakers *(possibly cache invalidation?)*, is there some way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away with later Windows updates and has not surfaced again that I've noticed. Therefore the solution appears to be "do nothing".